# Need to get PHP script to display results on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've seen many similar questions here, but I am just not knowledgeable enough in JS/AJAX/jQuery, or PHP, to understand how to translate it into a solution for my problem.

I have a contact form which links to contact.php to actually send the email. It is currently working, but instead of displaying "message sent" on the same page as I'd like it to, it brings the user to the PHP page.

Just to clarify: I want the results of the PHP echo to be displayed directly below the form on the HTML page.

Contact.php
http://pastie.org/8416873

Form
http://pastie.org/8416875

Comment: Do you know what AJAX is?

Comment: You need to know why people use ajax . Reason of using AJAX is is to avoid page redirects or refresh . You want to use ajax but want to redirect page .

Comment: I don't want to redirect the page, I wish for the user to see "message sent" directly below the form: "It is currently working, but instead of displaying "message sent" on the same page as I'd like it to, it brings the user to the PHP page."

Comment: @Jared Makes no sense

Comment: I've just updated the top post, please take a look now.

Comment: I remember you! And your script. What the user wants is to display message sent below the form, because currently, the form is on an html file, and the content are executed on a PHP file. To do this, you need to be able to use AJAX. Here's a tutorial: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ajax-html5-css3-contact-form-tutorial/, it will explain everything. It's very clear and you'll pick it up in no time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can remove the action from your form, and do something like:

HTML:

```
<form class="contact_form" method="post" name="contact_form">

            <ul>
                <li>

                </li>
                <li>
                     <label for="name">Name:</label>
                     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="JohnDoe@Email.com" required />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="message">Message:</label>
                    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="submit btn btn-default" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </form>
        <div class="targetDiv"></div>
```

And javascript:

```
 function formSubmit(e){

     e.preventDefault(); //This will prevent the default click action.

    var frm = $('.contact_form'),
        data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            $('.targetDiv').text('Your message has been sent!');
        },  
        error: function() {
           //your error message here
        }   
    }); 
    return false; 
   }   
}
```